# Build Error : Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in New Project

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I reopened my old Ionic project and when i tried to build it  i got "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error.

**Note: I updated my Android Studio Recently**

I have tried uninstalling and installing node and ionic

**Error**

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=H:\sdk (DEPRECATED)
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.
```

**ionic info :**

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 5.2.7
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.5
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.2

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic
-webview 4.1.1, (and 4 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.2.8

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 25.2.3 (H:\sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.16.3 (J:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.11.2
   OS                : Windows 8.1
```

I am getting this error while running **ionic cordova build android**. It isn't building. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did your code work before? Maybe you should try to downgrade your Android as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45025219/cordova-android-build-error-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined).

Comment: Yes it was working+ i tried with new Project too.but Same error. and That answer is lit. bit old .It will create a mess.

Comment: try to remove and add platform.

Comment: @Najam Thanks but already did it. still no luck

Comment: Downgrade Platofrm version to 7.0.0 or 7.0.1

Comment: @Najam you mean cordova platform add android@7.0.0 ? I did it . still no luck

Comment: I have never encountered this error before but I found [this github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5053) where a similar error for an older version is discussed. Maybe you should try ng serve or copy the project to a new folder and run npm install. If this doesn't help you should ask at the ionic board.