# in Cordova gradle -v showing gradle version but on cordova requirements give gradle not installed

Tags: cordova

i have installed cordova,created app ,added platform ..and trying to build

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-28,android-27,android-26,android-25,android-24
,Google Inc.:Google APIs:24,android-23,android-22,android-21,android-19,Google I
nc.:Google APIs:19,android-17
Gradle: not installed
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
Some of requirements check failed

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing gradle? Check the link to install gradle.
[Gradle installation](https://gradle.org/install/)

or go throw this StackOverflow post
[Cordova Android build error “Cannot read property 'length' of undefined”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45025219/cordova-android-build-error-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined)

Comment: i have installed when i try to type gradle -v its showing 5.6.2

Comment: Updated my post. Please check